# xcodebuild archive failed without reason

Tags: ios, xcode, xcodebuild

I'm trying to use xcodebuild (over fastlane) to archive my app, but it says
`** ARCHIVE FAILED ** Exit status: 65`
without giving any error or reason during `Touching MyApp.app`.
After the error I can see the archive in the organizer and there I can export successfully the app.

This is the command used:

```
set -o pipefail && xcodebuild -workspace ./AppName.xcworkspace -scheme AppName -configuration Release -destination 'generic/platform=iOS' -archivePath /Users/MyName/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2023-10-16/AppName.xcarchive clean archive | tee /Users/MyName/Library/Logs/gym/AppName.log | xcbeautify
```

In Xcode the app is archived successfully.
I tried with both Xcode 14.3.1 & 15.0.1

Do you know where I can get more hints or how to fix that?